# Weird cygwin executable

Tags: windows-7, unix, cygwin

yesterday i was looking at my cygwin bin folder and i found a exe name [.exe when i execute it , it says "[ : missing ]" like this -
[image]

when i execute it with ']' as a argument , it outputs nothing , could you please explain what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s an alias for `test`. See [man 1 test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> ## Name
>
> test - check file types and compare values
>
> ## Synopsis
>
> test *EXPRESSION*
>
> test
>
> [ *EXPRESSION* ]
> [ ]
> [ *OPTION*

The test command is sometimes used together with `if` to create a conditional block. It’s also useful on its own:

```
[ ! -d myDirectory ] && mkdir myDirectory
```

This would test whether a directory “myDirectory” does *not* exist and create it if that’s true.

Because it’s (also) for conditions, it must not print anything. Instead, it communicates via exit codes.

This command exists on virtually all GNU/Linux systems and many Unix variants.

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash) for a more in-depth explanation.